# PostgreSQL Insert on case

Tags: postgresql

I want to store in the `dining_table_grouping` table with the following columns:

- layout_id
- dining_table_id
- master_dining_table_id
- start_timestamp
- end_timestamp

values for each columns by an `insert` statement.

I want to apply a condition on this `insert` statement.

So if the values I want to store for the columns

- start_timestamp
- end_timestamp
- layout_id

already exist in these columns I want to furthermore check if the values I want to store in the columns

- dining_table_id
- master_dining_table_id

already exist in these columns. But either of those values should not exist in either of the two columns.

If both conditions are met, the values should not be stored.
If the first condition is met and second one not, then store the values.
If the first condition is not met but the second one, then store the values. (No need to check the second condition)
If none of the conditions is met, store the values.

Examples:

Values in the table:

```
1, 2, 3, 2019-03-13 08:00:00, 2019-03-13 09:00:00
```

Values I want to insert:

```
5, 4, 6, 2019-03-13 07:00:00, 2019-03-13 10:00:00
```

Result:

First condition is not met.
Values will be stored.

Values I want to insert:

```
5, 4, 2, 2019-03-13 07:00:00, 2019-03-13 10:00:00
```

Result:

First condition is not met.
Values will be stored.

Values I want to insert:

```
5, 4, 2, 2019-03-13 08:00:00, 2019-03-13 10:00:00
```

Result:

First condition is met.
Second one also.
Values will not be stored.

How can I achieve that?

A question which seems similar:

[Postgres CASE Statement in an insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158472/postgres-case-statement-in-an-insert)

I think my try only confuses, but still here it is:

```
INSERT INTO dining_table_grouping   
            ( 
                        id, 
                          layout_id, 
                          dining_table_id, 
                          master_dining_table_id, 
                          start_timestamp, 
                          end_timestamp   
            ) 
              
SELECT $1, 
         $2, 
         $3, 
         $4, 
         $5, 
         case  WHEN ( 
              layout_id <> $1 
       AND    start_timestamp <> $4 
       AND    end_timestamp <> $5) 
AND    ( 
              dining_table_id <> ($2, $3) 
       AND    master_dining_table_id <> ($2, $3)) end  
FROM   dining_table_grouping;
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: As @MauriceMeyer mentions, your syntax error comes from using `WHERE` more than once in a single `SELECT` statement. As far as your logic, could you clarify? It is very ambiguous as it is written now.

Comment: @Nick I tried to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are asking:

```
insert into dining_table_grouping (layout_id, dining_table_id, master_dining_table_id, start_timestamp, end_timestamp)
select $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
where not exists (
select * from dining_table_grouping where layout_id = $1 and start_timestamp = $4 and start_timestamp = $5 and (dining_table_id = $2 or dining_table_id = $3 or master_dining_table_id = $2 or master_dining_table_id = $3)
);
```